# std::string::size() strange behaviour

Tags: c++, std, stdstring

I believe the output has to do with UTF, but I do not know how. 
Would someone, please, explain?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "sizeof(char) = " << sizeof(char) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sizeof(std::string::value_type) = " << sizeof(std::string::value_type) << std::endl;

    std::string _s1 ("abcde");
    std::cout << "s1 = " << _s1 << ", _s1.size() = " << _s1.size() << std::endl;


    std::string _s2 ("abcdé");
    std::cout << "s2 = " << _s2 << ", _s2.size() = " << _s2.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
sizeof(char) = 1    
sizeof(std::string::value_type) = 1    
s1 = abcde, _s1.size() = 5    
s2 = abcdé, _s2.size() = 6
```

`g++ --version` prints `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609`

`QTCreator` compiles like this:

```
g++ -c -m32 -pipe -g -std=c++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I../strsize -I. -I../../Qt/5.5/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -o main.o ../strsize/main.cpp
g++ -m32 -Wl,-rpath,/home/rodrigo/Qt/5.5/gcc -o strsize main.o
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try printing `sizeof('é')` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

I added these two lines:

    `std::cout << "sizeof('é') = " << sizeof('é') << std::endl;`

    `std::cout << "sizeof(\"é\") = " << sizeof("é") << std::endl;`

And the output was:

    `sizeof('é') = 4`

    `sizeof("é") = 3`

Comment: @canellas `sizeof('é')` is likely promoting the `char` to `int`, that would explain why its size is 4. A string literal `"é"` is equivilent to a `const char[]`, so `sizeof("é")` is 3 because the `é` is encoded with 2 `char`s in UTF-8 (0xC3 0xA9) followed by the null terminator.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

I am still a bit lost... how can `std::cout` know that the bytes in  position 5 e 6 of `abcdé`  must be combined in a two byte value, before printing?

Comment: `how can std::cout know that the bytes in position 5 e 6 of abcdé must be combined in a two byte value, before printing?`: it doesn't. It blindly outputs the 6 bytes of the string, irrelevant of their content. Your *console* (ie. term/bash et all) is set to an UTF-8 environment and is displaying the appropriate glyph. See [How to set up a clean UTF-8 environment in Linux](https://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment).

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

é is encoded as 2 bytes, 0xC3 0xA9, in utf-8.

Answer (score 4):

`gcc` [default input character set is UTF-8](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html). Your editor also probably saved the file as UTF-8, so in your input .cpp file the string `abcdé` will have 6 bytes (As Peter already answered, the  [LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) is encoded in UTF-8 with 2 bytes). `std::string::length` returns the length in bytes, ie. 6. QED

You should open your source .cpp file in a hex editor to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

Even in C++11 `std::string` has nothing to do with UTF-8. In the [description](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) of `size` and `length` methods of `std::string` we can see:

> For std::string, the elements are bytes (objects of type char), which are not the same as characters if a multibyte encoding such as UTF-8 is used.

Thus, you should use some third-party unicode-compatible library to handle unicode strings.

If you continue to use non-unicode string classes with unicode strings, you may face LOTS of other problems. For example, you'll get a bogus result when trying to compare same-looking [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) and [precomposed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character).

Comment: This explains it very well. It's an irrelevant coincidence that UTF8 figures this at all.